# Unable to run with GraalVM a SpringBoot - Postgres application using Docker containers

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, docker, graalvm

On **Windows 10**, with I**ntelliJ Idea** I built a **Spring Boot** application (with the help of *Bootify.io*).

That application connects to a **Postgres Database** that resides in **Docker** (*container-postgres-1*) called *Bootifytwo*.

With the intention of playing and practicing with **GraalVM**, I downloaded a Docker image from *Oracle*.

From the corresponding GraalVM container (*container-graalvm-1*) I have been able to generate the **target/bootifytwo** executable.

But when I try to run it, it gives me a **database connection error**.

I put below all the **steps** that I executed, and after some **images**.

(Note the use of a **network** for intercommunication between the containers; as well as the use of **volumes** for each of the 2 containers).

Help with resolution would be appreciated.

```
Copy folder C:\CODIGO\IDEA_PROJECTS\bootifytwo to C:\Volumenes-Docker\vol-graalvm-1\bootifytwo

docker network create red-postgres-graalvm-1

docker run --name contenedor-postgres-1 -p 5433:5432 --network red-postgres-graalvm-1 -v "C:\Volumenes-Docker\vol-postgres-1:/var/lib/postgresql/data" -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -e POSTGRES_DB=bootifytwo -d postgres:13.9-alpine3.17

docker run --name contenedor-graalvm-1 -it --network=red-postgres-graalvm-1 -v "C:\Volumenes-Docker\vol-graalvm-1:/app" container-registry.oracle.com/graalvm/community:ol8-java17-22.3.0-b1 bash 

gu install native-image

cd bootifytwo

. ./mvnw native:compile -Pnative

docker start contenedor-graalvm-1
    
docker exec -it contenedor-graalvm-1 bash
                                        
./target/bootifytwo
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Instead [edit] your post to include the relevant logs/code as (properly formatted) text

Answer (score 1):

The postgresql db runs in an other docker than your application. So you can't connect with localhost.

Change your setup to connect to `contenedor-postgres-1`

Comment: Seems like a good idea, but it didn't work either: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to contenedor-postgres-1:5433 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections

Comment: Is postgres configured to listen on the external IP or just localhost?

Comment: I do not know. How can I find out?

Comment: Jump into the container, look for the postgresql.conf. Ther you find a configuration:`#listen_addresses`

Comment: listen_addresses = '*'

Comment: Finally it works using the IP instead of localhost

Comment: Now I get this error: Error creating bean with name 'viewResolver': Error creating bean with name 'thymeleafViewResolver': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'thymeleafViewResolver' parameter 1: Error creating bean with name 'layoutDialect': Instantiation of supplied bean failed